# Stretch drawable in the layer-list

Tags: android, xml, colors, drawable, shadow

I'm trying to add nice painted shadow to my circle float button. I made a layer-list, but the shadow image is behind the main color, and I can't make it bigger:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_bg_normal" />

        <item android:bottom="1dp"
              android:right="1dp">
            <shape
                  android:shape="oval"
                  android:padding="10dp">
                  <size android:height="@dimen/favorites_button_large_size"
                        android:width="@dimen/favorites_button_large_size" />
                  <solid android:color="@color/pink" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

I tried to make a shadow with gradient, but this looks much better

[image: shadow] -- here result if I comment/delete that pink ..

[image: main] -- here result if I uncomment/add pink solid shape

Comment: care to describe both images?

Comment: @pskink ? Can't understand you

Comment: can you describe both images, please?

Comment: @pskink ah, sure, one second

Comment: @pskink I've done that

Comment: try <inset> tag for pink solid shape

Comment: @pskink can you give me an example? I inserted inset tag in "item" shadow tag  http://codeshare.io/MaRBA

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Comment: you can also use <item> tag attributes

Comment: @pskink http://codeshare.io/MaRBA I tried this way, nothing happened. I aint sure, I use it in the right way

Comment: man, inset has android:inset[Top|Left|Right|Bottom] attributes...

Comment: also <item> has android:top, left, right and bottom, you can try them, in such case no need for <inset>

Comment: @pskink first I set only inset attr, and it didn't work. Now inserted for Top, Btm... and it works, great thanks!

Comment: so <inset> doesnt work?

Comment: @pskink no, it works. But that's not for me. I tried to hardcode paddings and inset, and it crashed on other layouts